# Editable textarea revert in a single-page developer React won't re-render on changed data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am experimenting with a single-page app. So, my page has in the `<head>`:

```
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
```

and in the `<body>`

```
    <div id="jsoneditor"></div>
```

and in the `<script>`:

```
        const loaderRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('jsoneditor'));
```

and

```
        const JSONEditor = () => {

            const revertJSONData = () => {
                const reminders = getMyReminders();
                //setState( {
                //    value: reminders
                //});
            }

            console.log( "JSON Editor Rendering");
            const reminders = getMyReminders();
            console.log( `JSON: ${JSON.stringify(reminders)}`);
            return (
                <div>
                    <form>
                        <textarea id="newjson" name="message" rows="10" cols="30" defaultValue={JSON.stringify(reminders,null,2)}/>
                    </form>
                    <input class="button" name="revert" type="submit" value="revert" onClick={() => {revertJSONData()}} />
                </div>
            );
        };
```

and of course there are places where I trigger rendering of the element:

```
                    loaderRoot.render(<JSONEditor />);
```

This works as intended, except for one thing. My problem is that on clicking the revert button, the element should re-render the textarea based on the data in my app (which can also be changed in other ways), overriding whatever has been edited (or not). But my component doesn't get re-rendered based on the changed data. I was looking at setState to tell React it needs to change, but setState is not available in this setup. Currently, I can only get this refreshed by reloading the entire page.

Is there a way I can force React to re-render my `<textarea>` element, overriding any changes that may have been edited in it?